# Call many functions in BODY

Tags: javascript

Call many functions in BODY
How can we call 2 functions (javascript) in onload of body in aspx? The functions are independent

Answer (score 6):

```
<body onload="function1(); function2();">
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try calling the functions one after the other like shown below?

```
<body onLoad="javascript: yourFunction(); yourOtherFunction();">...</body>
```